# How to disconnect toolbar action from fragment Android

Tags: android, fragment, action, toolbar

My application has ONE activity and three types of fragments.

`MainActivity` has the `ToolBar`, and fragments add their own actions into this `ToolBar`- so fragments don't have their own `ToolBar`.

1. (A) fragment is `formFragmet` with `EditText`, `CheckBox`, `Spinner`, date
   and time fields. It has the action in the `ToolBar` which updates
   those fields when a user change something in them.
2. (B) fragment is a `ListFragment`, and it has the list of records -
   it doesn't need to have actions in the `ToolBar`.
3. (C) fragment is a tabbed fragment which can contain both (A)
   fragment and (B) fragment, or any other combination in tabs
   (`ViewPager`). `TabbedFragment` doesn't need any action in the
   `ToolBar`, but if a `FormFragment` (A) is in the current tab, it
   displays the actions for that `FormFragment`, so it's ok, and it
   works fine.

**Problem is this:**

When a user selects a record from the `ListFragment`(B) next screen is `FormFragment`(A), and the user to changes the values in fields. After that, user selects an action from the `ToolBar` (update), and the form is updated.

After successful update, user then goes back (touches the arrow in the `ToolBar`added by the Activity it pops `BackStack`, and shows `ListFragment`) to `ListFragment`(B) and user chooses another item in the list. Another (new) `FormFragment` opens up with different data in fields.

User changes something in this form, and presses update action in the toolbar.

Change is NOT saved! The reason is that the action from the `ToolBar` in this (new) `formFragment` is still attached to the PREVIOUS `FormFragment`???

Has anyone had this issue???

Is there a way of somehow detaching the action from the fragment?

I guessed that the Android would set the new action in the toolbar to the new fragment when created. But obviously it's not doing that.

Please if someone could help.

P.S.
I will provide some parts of the code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is: use the getChildFragmentManager() in TabbedPagerAdapter.

I was using the Activity's getSupportFragmentManager() which is wrong when you are using NESTED fragments like in TabbedFragment which has a ViewPager, and a ViewPager has (child) Fragments inside.